# The relationship of free, divisible, projective, injective, and flat modules.

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, projective-module, injective-module

In general, we have that:

*free $\Rightarrow$ projective $\Rightarrow$ flat*

*injective $\Rightarrow$  divisible ( ($\Rightarrow$) be ($\Leftrightarrow$) in PIDs)*

Simple Counter-examples:

**projective but not free:** $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is $\mathbb{Z}_6$  projective but not $\mathbb{Z}_6$ free

**flat but not projective:** $\mathbb{Q}$

My questions:

> 1) Please give counter-examples: divisible but not injective, flat but not injective.
>
> 2) In proof about $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module, I use 2 properties:

First: $P$ is projective $\Leftrightarrow$  there is a free module $F$ and an $R$-module $K$ such that $F≅K⊕P$.

Second: Every submodule of a free module in PID is free.

The first is easy to prove but the second isn't. Other way to prove $\mathbb{Q}$ is not projective that use projective basis, but really it's difficult to understand for me.

> So is there other way?

Thanks for regarding!

Comment: What notion of "divisible" are you using? There are at least two..

Comment: @rschwieb: u can see more about divisible module at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisibleModule.html

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ is a flat module over itself but it is not injective. That one was easy :-)

Comment: $\Bbb Q(x)/\Bbb Z[x]$ is a divisible-not-injective $\Bbb Z[x]$ module. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379248/disprove-injectivity Seek and ye shall find.

Answer (score 7):

1st question answered in comments. For 2nd:

> Lemma: Let $R$ be a domain s.t there is an $R$-module, $M$, which is nonzero, projective and injective $R$-module. then $R$ is a field.

$\mathbb{Q}$ is a nonzero and injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module (as you mentioned *injective* $\Leftrightarrow$  *divisible* in  *PIDs*). $\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain and not field. now use lemma.