# Example of divisible module that is not injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, injective-module

We know that every injective module is divisible, but I can't find an example of divisible module such that it is not injective.

Comment: see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=r9VoYbk-8c4C&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=divisible+module+not+injective&source=bl&ots=Gm3m5yNMtY&sig=e42A0YVxtrOwmm3c8c-eiXV-7wM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HU3eVNThIoG3UufmgcAL&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=divisible%20module%20not%20injective&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
*Joseph Rotman* in the book *An Introduction to Homological Algebra* says

> "a domain $R$ is a *dedekind* ring if and only if every divisible module is injective" (Theorem 4.24)

so you can consider a domain that is not a *dedekind* ring

Comment: This answer doesn't provide a concrete example. (In fact, it doesn't provide anything, because a domain which is not Dedekind can have divisible modules which are injective.) A concrete example can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379248/disprove-injectivity).

Comment: @user26857. right; i doubt if op wanted concrete example(this answer is only a hint in this case) or wanted to sure that there exists some examples and sure converse of "*every injective module is divisible*" is not right. thanks you op for acceptation. BTW thank you for [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379248/divisible-module-which-is-not-injective) link

Comment: "but I can't find an *example* of..."

Comment: as you see this is a Hint. it suggest that one can look for quotient of injective modules (in a domain that is not a dedekind ring), since the proof says there exist at list one quotient of an injective module such that is divisible but not injective. BTW, i agree that this answer does not give an explicit example.