# Use of "$A$ is a domain" in the proof that $Q$ is an injective $A$-module iff it is divisible

Tags: commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, injective-module

Let $A$ be a PID. Then, an $A$-module $Q$ is injective iff $Q=rQ$ for every $r\neq 0$ in $A$.

My question is, where is the property "A is a domain" used in the proof of the above? Can someone please provide a suitable proof to point this out?

Comment: $Q$ also has to be torsion-free.

Comment: Okay, where does the problem arise if its not?

Comment: I didn't check, but I guess you can't satisfy Baer's  criterion.

Comment: Torsion free is not required. Since the D in PID stands for domain, are you asking whether a similar result can be proved for non-domains? If so, what type of rings do you want to consider other than PIDs?

Comment: To elaborate on Mohan's comment re: Bernard's comment, $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: More generally, if $R$ is a ring such that its total ring of fractions, $T(R)$, is a finite product of fields, then $R$ is hereditary if and only if divisible $R$-modules are injective.  Among domains, this characterizes *Dedekind domains.*

Comment: (cont.) The first result I mentioned does not, as far as I know, even extend to $T(R)$ being Von Neumann Regular.  It seems to be key that every dense ideal of $R$ contains a nonzerodivisor, and that $(Ann(I), I)$ is a dense ideal for every ideal $I$ (aka that $R$ is reduced). My main point is that being a domain, and also having principal ideals, is way overpowered for "divisible $\implies$ injective."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is not a domain. Then $rQ=Q$ cannot hold for all $r\ne0$, unless $Q=\{0\}$.

Indeed, if $r,s\in R$ are nonzero with $rs=0$, we have
$$
\{0\}=0Q=rsQ=rQ=Q
$$

On the other hand, it's a standard result of module theory that every module can be embedded in an injective module.

In general, a module $Q$ over a commutative ring $R$ is called *divisible* if, for every *nonzero-divisor* $r\in R$, we have $rQ=Q$ (note that $0$ *is* a zero-divisor). Every injective module is divisible: indeed, if $r$ is a nonzero-divisor and $x\in Q$, the homomorphism $rR\to Q$ defined by $rs\mapsto sx$ is well defined and it extends to a homomorphism $R\to Q$. If the image of $1$ is $y$, then it's clear that $ry=x$. Therefore $rQ=Q$.

On the other hand, being divisible does not generally imply that the module is injective even over domains, see [Divisible module which is not injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/379248/62967)

Comment: This shows that there cannot be non-trivial divisible module over non-integral rings. To be 100% complete, it should also be mentioned that there are non-trivial injective modules over such rings.

Comment: @CaptainLama I added the mention

Comment: @egreg I think this is really demonstrating why nobody uses this as the definition for divisible over general rings.  A more common definition would be that $rM =M$ for every *non-zerodivisor $r \in R$*, which is still true for every injective module.  I recognize that you are exactly answering the question as asked, but still thought this might be worth pointing out.

Comment: @BadamBaplan Is the addition fulfilling your request?

Comment: @egreg yes, to me that is a valuable addition!

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of the comments I left on your post.

Let $R$ a PID and $M$ a divisible $R$-module.  We invoke Baer's criterion to show that $M$ is injective.  Given any homomorphism $\phi: I \rightarrow M$ where $I$ is an ideal of $R$, we need to show that $\phi$ extends to a homomorphism $R \rightarrow M$.  But $I = aR$ for some $a \in R$. We know that $M = aM$, so we find $m \in M$ such that $\phi(a) = am$.  Then the map $\phi': R \rightarrow M$ defined by $\phi'(r) = rm$ extends $\phi$.

Where did $R$ being a domain come into this? To be able to use Baer's criterion, we needed to be able to work with an arbitrary ideal $I$.  If $R$ was just a Principal Ideal Ring, then we might have $I = aR$ for a zero-divisor $a$.  As egreg pointed out, the condition that $M = aM$ for all $0 \not= a \in R$ is ridiculous for rings with zero divisors, because it forces $M = 0$.  So we usually generalize the notion of "divisible" modules to mean something like $M = IM$ for every ideal $I$ that contains a non-zerodivisor — in any case if we focus on principal ideal rings most reasonable notions of module divisibility will converge.

So how to move past the domain case?  **Let's show that things still work out fine when $R$ is a reduced principal ideal ring**.  Then $\operatorname{Ann}(I) \cap I = 0$ for every ideal $I$, and given a homomorphism $\phi: I \rightarrow M$ we can extend it to a homomorphism $\phi^*: (I, \operatorname{Ann}(I)) \rightarrow M$ by defining $\phi(\operatorname{Ann}(I) = 0$.  If $R$ is a Principal Ideal Ring then $(I, \operatorname{Ann}(I)) = aR$ for $a$ necessarily not a zerodivisor, and we can proceed as above.

More generally, there is the following result:

> Let $R$ be a ring such that $T(R)$, the total ring of fractions of $R$, is a finite product of fields.  $R$ is hereditary iff divisible $R$-modules are injective.

This is I think due to Levy in *Torsion-free and divisible modules over non-integral domains* (1963), and can be generalized to noncommutative rings just as well.